# How to find Paypal sandbox credentials for Braintree sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

Trying to link a Paypal sandbox account with a Braintree sandbox.

Braintree sandbox requires **email**, **client id** and **client secret** to link to a paypal sandbox account, as shown in this screenshot from [Braintree 
Gateway](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/).

[image]

In Paypal Developer website, i followed the instructions on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications) and generated a sandbox access token for Braintree. After doing that, the blue account link at the bottom appeared:

[image]

However, when i click that sandbox account link, it displays the following:

[image]

This is not the **email**, **client id** and **client secret** that Braintree asked for.

Where *exactly* can i find these three items on the Paypal Developer website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help from the PayPal Developer website.

[image]

In the "REST API apps" section, you need to press the "Create App" button to make a new App, choose any name for it.

Once created, that app's credentials will work with Braintree Sandbox.

Comment: Thank you @Arvind, I'm grateful

Comment: My Sandbox doesn't showing up `Secret` when I click on `Show` link. This happens only for `Sandbox` tab but `Live` tab it is working. Any idea?